# Laravel - Making a HasManyThrough Relationship provide a unique collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, has-many-through

I am having an issue getting a hasManyThrough to work:

```
public function deliveryContainers() : HasManyThrough
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        DeliveryContainer::class, // Final
        StockMovement::class, // Intermediate
        'product_id', // Foreign key on Intermediate
        'id', // Foreign key on Final
        'product_id', // Local key on Current
        'location_id' // Local key on Intermediate
    )->where('delivery_id', $this->delivery_id);
}
```

Because the stockMovements table returns multiple results, my resulting delivery containers collection contains duplicate entries. If I could somehow put a group/unique on the intermediate table query then this would be resolved.

I can get a collection with the correct deliveryContainers eager loaded using the following:

```
public function deliveryContainers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(StockMovement::class, 'entity_id', 'delivery_id')
        ->with('deliveryContainer')
        ->where('product_id', $this->product_id)
        ->get()
        ->unique('location_id');
}
```

However, to access the deliveryContainer I now have the following:

```
foreach($this->deliveryContainers() as $row){
    $row->deliveryContainer->id;    
}
```

And what I would like to have...

```
foreach($this->deliveryContainers() as $row){
    $row->id;
}
```

Is there any way to push the eager loaded relationship up a level (if that can be used to describe it), or even better add some kind of unique filter to the hasManyThrough relationship?

**Table Structure**

delivery_exceptions (where this relationship originates)

- product_id
- delivery_id

delivery_containers

- id
- delivery_id

stock_movements

- entity_id (linked to delivery id)
- product_id

**Relationships**

- A *delivery exception* belongsTo a product
- A *product* hasMany stock_movements
- A *stock movement* belongsTo a *delivery container*
- A *delivery exception* hasMany *delivery containers*... (indirectly, through a combination of the product and the stock movements)

Comment: How exactly do your models look like and what are their keys and other relationship definitions?

Comment: Are these really all the keys and foreign keys on the `delivery_containers` table? Because if so, why do you need a `hasManyThrough` relationship at all? On `delivery_exceptions`, you have a `delivery_id` which you find again on the `delivery_containers`. So it looks quite straight forward to me...

Comment: Delivery containers actually requires a relationship to the stock movement table in order to split the delivery into delivery containers. A delivery has many delivery containers and a delivery containers has many products. I am trying to find all delivery containers which a product from a delivery exists within

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a really tough setup there and I'm not entirely sure that I got the full idea behind it (also because of you using `entity_id` at some place instead of `delivery_id`). But nonetheless, I gave it a shot.

The `hasManyThrough` relationship you defined looks actually not too bad, but in my opinion there is a better way to get to the result. But first let's have a look at your relationships:

```
                                               3
                            +-------------------------------------+
               4            v                                     |
        +-------------> Delivery <----------+                     |
        |                                   | 1                   |
        +                                   +                     +
DeliveryException +---> Product <---+ StockMovement +---> DeliveryContainer
        +                                                         ^
        +---------------------------------------------------------+
                                      2
```

As a `StockMovement` already belongs to a `DeliveryContainer`, which in return belongs to a `Delivery`, the relation from `StockMovement` to `Delivery` (marked as `1`) seems obsolete to me. Anyway, to get relation `2` on your model, you can use the paths `3` and `4` to your advantage:

```
class DeliveryException
{
    public function deliveryContainers(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(DeliveryContainer::class, 'delivery_id', 'delivery_id');
    }
}
```

Obviously, this will give you all the `DeliveryContainers`, unfiltered by the `Product`. Therefore I suggest adding a second function:

```
public function deliveryContainersByProduct(): HasMany
{
    return $this->deliveryContainers()
        ->whereHas('stockMovements', function ($query) {
             $query->where('product_id', $this->product_id);
        });
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for your effort in helping on this. It works perfectly!

Comment: I actually got something else working in the mean time (but your solution is way more elegant and I am going to switch to this now). My other solution posted as another answer for reference.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is far more elegant, but this is another way to do this too:

```
public function deliveryContainers1()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        DeliveryContainer::class, // Final
        StockMovement::class, // Intermediate
        'product_id', // Foreign key on Intermediate
        'id', // Foreign key on Final
        'product_id', // Local key on Current
        'location_id' // Local key on Intermediate
    )
        ->where('delivery_id', $this->delivery_id)
        ->distinct();
}
```

Comment: I wonder why your solution requires a `distinct() `. The generated query should not retrieve duplicates without it either. But I'll give this solution a try myself, it looks interesting anyway.

Comment: I think it is because it gets each delivery container for each stock movement. While the stock movements are all unique, they in turn reference the duplicated delivery containers.

Comment: I don't think so. Because if you have three models `A`, `B` and `C` where `A` has many `B` and `B` has many `C`, you will also be able to create a relation saying `A` has many `C` through `B`. And in this scenario, the created sql query will look something like this (sql server syntax): `select * from [c] inner join [b] on [b].[id] = [c].[b_id] where [b].[a_id] = ?` (`?` is a placeholder for the `id` of an instance of `A`). So it is actually impossible to retrieve the same model twice. But of course this relationships are more straight forward than yours...